# Converting point data into gridded dataframe for histogram analysis using R?

Tags: raster, r, kriging

I am very new at using GIS data and only modestly experienced with R.  I've been reading about how to analyze spatial data using the spatial-analyst.net PDF book, so I'm not completely lost, but I thought I could describe my problem and people might suggest ideas.

I have a dataset with about 2000 measurements at different lat/long coordinates, although I will probably subdivide this dataset as the data was collected over 3 years and conditions changed over time.  Let's call the variable being measured "IP."

I want to create a map of IP in the full area under question using Kriging or some other interpolation method on the sample data.  Then I want to create a histogram measuring the amount of land in various IP buckets.  I will also need to create a histogram which shows the number of samples in each bucket (note a sample could have a higher or lower actual IP than what kriging predicts for its land).

I follow how to load the data into a SpatialPointsDataFrame and run a kriging analysis, **where I'm having trouble is how to convert that data into a gridded dataframe so I can do the histogram analysis.**

Any suggestions for converting points into grids?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right ... it is pretty easy! The "raster" package has some pretty straightforward ways of dealing with creating and manipulating rasters.

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)

# Load your point shapefile (with IP values in an IP field):
pts <- readShapePoints("pts.shp")

# Create a raster, give it the same extent as the points
# and define rows and columns:

rast <- raster()
extent(rast) <- extent(pts) # this might be unnecessary
ncol(rast) <- 20 # this is one way of assigning cell size / resolution
nrow(rast) <- 20

# And then ... rasterize it! This creates a grid version 
# of your points using the cells of rast, values from the IP field:
rast2 <- rasterize(pts, rast, pts$IP, fun=mean)
```

You can assign grid size and resolution in a number of ways - have a good look at the raster package documentation.

The values of the raster cells from rasterize can be calculated with a function - 'mean' in the example above. Make sure you put this in: otherwise it just uses the value of IP from the *last* point it comes across!

---

From a CSV:

```
pts <- read.csv("IP.csv")
coordinates(pts) <- ~lon+lat
rast <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
extent(rast) <- extent(pts)
rasterize(pts, rast, pts$IP, fun = mean)
```

Comment: Hey this is very useful, but how would the code look if I started with the points in a simple CSV with lat/longs rather than a shapefile?  The columns in the CSV would be IP, Lat, Long, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: You did indicate that you've already loaded the data into a SpatialPointsDataFrame ... which is exactly what `pts` is in my example above. Just run the code on your SpatialPointsDataFrame object!

Comment: This reply, although excellent, does not seem to address what is needed.  (It appears to offer a solution to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20018/ instead.)  The challenge is to *interpolate* 2000 or so points, not just assign their values to raster cells.  Given that the OP claims already to have "run a kriging analysis," this question comes down to *extracting* the values of a raster (say, `r`) for using in a `hist`-like procedure, which is simply a matter of an expression like `hist(getValues(r))`.

Comment: @whuber - Looks like OP asks "where I'm having trouble is how to convert that data into a gridded dataframe so I can do the histogram analysis ... any suggestions for converting points into grids" as the actual question, and knows how to make a SpatialPointsDataFrame and run the kriging. But you're right, it seems to be a duplicate of 20018 (except for gridded input).

Comment: Apologies, @user1080253 ... I read 'grid' as 'raster' which isn't correct, and not helpful for kriging; see [here](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/442) for a better idea on creating a regular grid and interpolating your data **to** that grid.

Comment: @user1080253 - The pdf book from spatial-analyst.net that you mentioned sounds useful, but I haven't been able to find it at that site. Could you post a link to it? Like you, I'm new to GIS and only modestly experienced with R and looking for good materials for self-teaching.

Comment: @user1080253, Google found it using terms "book spatial-analyst.net"; I should have tried that first.

Answer (score 4):

The plotKML package has a function called `vect2rast`. This function basically extends the `rasterize` function available in the raster package. The advantage of `vect2rast`; however, is that it requires no input from the user's side i.e. it automatically determines the grid cell size and the bounding box based on the properties of the input data set. The grid cell size is estimated based on the density/size of features in the map (`nndist` function in spatstat package).

```
library(plotKML)
Rast2 <- vect2rast(pts)

# for large data sets use SAGA GIS:
Rast2 <- vect2rast(pts, method = "SAGA")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting from a spatialPoints object you just do the following:

```
# Convert spatialpoints object to a 'conventional' dataframe
spatial_points_dataframe  <- data.frame(spatial_points_object)

# View the first few rows
head(spatial_points_dataframe)
```