# Count number of points inside a pixel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point, vector

For a project I want to count the number of points in a raster, just like the picture below, in order to get idea of the point density. It seems simple but for some reason I am unable to find away to do this.

[image: raster with points]

Comment: Is it really a raster or just Square polygons (vector data)? Have you tried "Count Points in polygon" tool?

Comment: I am familiar with the count points in polygon tool, however that is not what I am looking for. From my vector points i want to create a new raster layer (100m by 100m), which shows  how many points are in the individual pixels.

Comment: You could build off of @BERA's suggestion. Run "Count Points in Polygon" and then rasterize that polygon grid layer with the raster value being the count attribute.

Comment: @ycartwhelen you could add that as an answer

Comment: @BERA A very well described version of our joint answer has been given on another GIS SE question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94358/converting-point-layer-to-raster-grid-that-shows-frequency-of-points-per-cell-ui). @@NanderBras Welcome to GIS SE - we're glad to have you here! Before posting questions it's a good idea to check if other have people have already asked the same question in the past to avoid duplicate questions. That way all answers on a topic go in one place, and there is less reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting point layer to raster grid that shows frequency of points per cell uisng QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94358/converting-point-layer-to-raster-grid-that-shows-frequency-of-points-per-cell-ui)