# How to convert a regular point grid to raster?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, rasterization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a point grid to a raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32250/how-to-convert-a-point-grid-to-a-raster)

I´d like to convert a regular grid (25 meter) of points (XYZ) to a raster. I have tried the GRASS-tool r.in.xyz but I always get a integer raster where all cells have a value of 1.

Answer (score 5):

Go Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize. Set a vector layer to process, a field with values and desired raster size.

Comment: Thank you SS_Rebelious, it works but I´ve still one problem: The points I have are mid points, after rasterizing, the point is located at the corner of a cell. The raster should be moved 12.5 m to the west and north. Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: @ GISbert, this is a subject for another question: you should provide a screenshots and information about projections used in vector layer, project and raster. And may be even sample of your data to play with.